# Castle Windsor - Specify all interceptors

Tags: castle-windsor

```
container
    .Register
    (
        AllTypes
            .FromAssemblyContaining<TestInterceptor>()
            .BasedOn<IInterceptor>()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Interceptor"))
            .WithService.AllInterfaces()
            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient),

        Component
            .For<IRepository>()
            .ImplementedBy<LogRepository>()
            .Interceptors
            (
                InterceptorReference.ForType<TestInterceptor>(),
                InterceptorReference.ForType<TestTwoInterceptor>(),
                InterceptorReference.ForType<TestThreeInterceptor>()
            ).Anywhere
    );
```

Is there an easy way to specify that a component will use all interceptors instead of having to specify each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting problem. There's no out of the box way to solve it in the fluent API, mostly because most of the time you **do** want to have a fine grained control over which interceptors to apply, and in what order. This is a surgical tool.

Anyway, if you're sure you need to go this way register the interceptors first, then grab their names (via `container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(IInterceptor))`) and in a loop apply all of them to the component.